# Querying Data NODE ANGULAR

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Hi I'm new to MEAN stack, so it would be kind of anyone to answer me in detail.

I'm sending a simple json from view(angular) to NODE:

**view** code:

```
<select class="btn btn-success" data-ng-model="difficulty" data-ng-options="type for type in difficultydropdown"></select>
<select class="btn btn-success" data-ng-model="type" data-ng-options="type for type in typedropdown"></select>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="query_data(difficulty,type)">Query</button>
```

**controller** code:

```
app.factory('resultService', function($resource){
  return $resource('/api/results');
});

app.controller('resultsController', function(resultService, $scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.difficultydropdown =["","Level 1","Level 2","Level 3","Level 4","Level 5"];
  $scope.typedropdown =["","Single","Multiple"];
 $scope.query_data = function (difficulty,type){
    $scope.query = {difficulty : difficulty, type :type };
    resultService.get($scope.query);
  };
});
```

**node** code:

```
  router.route('/results').get(function(req,res){
    console.log(req.query);
    Question.find(req.query).exec(function(err, questions){
        if(err){
            console.error(err.stack);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(questions);
            return res.status(200).send(questions);
        }
    });
});
```

this print the required result of the find query on terminal.

Now what I want to know is how to receive this data on client side.

Answer (score 0):

*It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.*

You can read more at $recourse documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

So in your controller:

```
$scope.results = resultService.get($scope.query);
```

And in your view:

```
<pre>{{results | json}}</pre>
```

In the background angular will populate the actual data in your variable when the $http promise is fulfilled!

Comment: Thanks that i knew the solution you have provided I have tried that already, i get following error in the browser console..Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array (Request: GET /api/results)

Comment: Also I'm able to get complete test data set with service.query(), but what i really wanted was to send json object to query the data so that i get only that response that is queried on the server not the while dataset given by service.query().

Comment: Solved Instead of using resultService.get($scope.query) use resultService.query($scope.query),further for sake of knowledge .get() returns an object while .query() returns an array.